# Can K-means be used to group data in win/lose categorical values for prediction purposes?

Tags: r, machine-learning, k-means

Currently I have a dataset with matches played by a team against other teams. Some of the variables are: kills, deads, assists, amountgold, amountdamagedone, result(win/lose). What I want to do is predict if an observation/row should belong to win or lose without knowing the result(win/lose) variabel so that the team can make test data and look what stats needs to be achieved to win or lose a game.

I was thinking about usin K-means, but I don't know if that will work out for me, because giving the input, the output will be clustering based on patterns in the data. But I dont know which cluster belongs to win and lose. Does anyone have advice for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the outcome of interest `result(win/lose)` for past data then this is a task for a supervised algorithm, not an unsupervised one (such as k-means). You could use k-means, but why would you? Maybe to find some hidden patterns, but since your goal is to predict the result then I don't see the point.

A very simple algorithm (and close in spirit to k-means) would be the k-nn algorithm, which would give you the probability (or class, with some threshold) of a given observation being a win or a loss.

Comment: Thank you very much! Will it work in my case you think? I got a lot of observations. Per observarion got the variable kill/dead/damage/result(win/lose) etc.. is it possble with k-nn to use this data (so use all variables) to decide if one row without the result should be a win/lose? This is my last question I think!

Comment: @MYil This really depends on how big your data is, and how much computational power you have. Only one way to find out, try it and see for yourself. But this shouldn't be a problem for modern computers, again, unless you have a huge dataset.